# Missing class properties transform pdfjs-dist

Tags: reactjs

I have Installed **npm install pdfjs-dist** i want to load PDF on the browser on mobile phones. However I am getting the below error. How can i resolve this?

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js
SyntaxError: C:\node\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build\pdf.js: Missing class properties transform.
  3520 |
  3521 | class PixelsPerInch {
> 3522 |   static CSS = 96.0;
       |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  3523 |   static PDF = 72.0;
  3524 |   static PDF_TO_CSS_UNITS = this.CSS / this.PDF;
  3525 | }
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a resolution? I am having a simliar issue with pdfjs-dist but on a different line of code

Comment: No I am still searching for an answer only commercial versions are available